# How did this class get included through transitive dependencies?

Tags: c++, include, clion

I am developing in C++ (using CLion).  When I am trying to understand a class I am using, I can mouse over it and go to the definition, and that works great.

What I can't always figure out is the path that got that class included in my code.  I have headers that I include, and they have their own include headers, which have their own, and somewhere buried in all that is the class I am now looking at.  This is particular frustrating when there are conflicts or collisions.

Is there a tool that shows this path?

(Note that this is not trying to get the dependency tree, which I am doing already.)

Comment: FWIW, this is why your own code should be in it's own namespace and you should never use `using namespace name_of_namespace;`.

Comment: You could have the compiler dump the preprocessed source and then trace through that by hand. Ok, that's probably a really terrible approach.